# ¿Como puedo generar un pdf horizontal con thymeleaf y spring?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

Tengo un sistema que tiene `personas` registradas, y he generado un reporte de todas ellas con distintos `datos` pero el pdf se descarga de manera vertical, por lo que los `campos` al ser tantos no se visualizan correctamente, como puedo generar el pdf horizontal?

```
 public static ByteArrayInputStream allPersonsReport(List<Person> persons) {

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL.rotate());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        Context context = setContextAllPerson(persons);

        String html = templateEngine.process("templates/report_all_persons", context);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
        document.open();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
        document.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GeneratePdfReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }
```